# val jquery not pass to the value how to fix this laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

controller

```
  return response()->json([
             'category' => $category,
             'editRoute' => $artistCategoriesEditRoute
       ]);
```

response

```
category    Object { id: 1, title: "tt", parent_id: 0, … }
id  1
title   "tt"
parent_id   0
slug    "55"
description "rg"
artist_id   1
created_at  "2022-07-25 15:25:46"
updated_at  "2022-07-25 15:25:46"
editRoute   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/artist/edit_categories/1"
```

blade

```
                               <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Category name">

       $(document).on("click", '#edit', function () {
         
          var userURL = $(this).data('url');
          $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
          $.get(userURL, function (data) {

            $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show');
 
            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
              $('#title').val(value.title)

$('#slug').val(value.slug)


$('#description').val(value.description);
  alert(value.title );
});
          
   

              $('#edit_forms').attr('actions', data.editRoute);
     
          })

       });
```

here am trying to show text val in ajax   alert(value.title ) show correct data.but               $('#title').val(value.title) not workig how to fix this problem

Comment: You're looping through `data` and setting the value of the same `#title` field in every iteration of the loop, so only the final value will be shown. It's possible the last value is empty. Alternatively, are you sure there's only 1 instance of an element with `id="title"` in the DOM? If there's multiple, this is an error which needs to be fixed. Lastly, as you sure the AJAX request is even working properly? Check the console for errors *after* you make the request.

Answer (score 0):

Here I saw that you sent only one category as response, So you should not use each function.
You should access category data directly.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", '#edit', function() {
        var userURL = $(this).data('url');
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.get(userURL, function(data) {
            $('#staticBackdrop').modal('show');
            $('#title').val(data.category.title)
            $('#slug').val(data.category.slug)
            $('#description').val(data.category.description);
            alert(data.category.title);
            $('#edit_forms').attr('actions', data.editRoute);

        })

    });
</script>
```